# A robust way to execute a command/run a script at login?

Tags: shell-script, x11, login, profile

I have two commands that change keyboard behaviour:

```
 xset r rate 120 66
 /usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"
```

When I open a terminal and execute them, they change auto-repeat settings and remap CAPS LOCK to control, not only in the terminal window but for my whole desktop environment.

I'd like them to be run automatically when I login to my account (either using a GUI or via ssh/etc.).  I'd like to do this in a robust way (i.e. I don't want to use distribution-specific tools) and I don't want to use any GUI tools.

I supposed that there is some file that is executed at login and I should just paste these commands there, but adding them to `~/.bash_login` didn't have any effect, similarly with `~/.bash_profile`.  With `~/.profile`, only `/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"` had effect.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you put X related items that you'd like to run in the context of the user (you) in one of 2 files:

- $HOME/.xsession
- $HOME/.xinitrc
- For GNOME desktops you can put commands in $HOME/.gnomerc
- For KDE you put commands in $HOME/.kde/Autostart

#### Alternative Approach

Some commands such as `xset` may not work from within these files. If you'd still like to automate something like this you may be able to add it as a "Startup Application".

**Step #1**

Create a shell script, `xset.bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash
xset r rate 120 66
```

**Step #2**

Add a startup task to run the shell script.

Open the application *Startup Applications*, under *System →  Preferences*

[image: ss of dialog #1]

Then click the *Add* button

[image: ss of add dialog]

Once you're done OK & Close the dialogs and to test it out logout and log back in.

#### References

- [Starting Your X Session: .xinitrc and .xsession](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/workshops/cool_unix/xinitrc.html)

Comment: It doesn't work - the `xset` command still doesn't have any effect.  Actually, maybe the problem is that it is overwritten by gnome settings?  But how would i change that?

Comment: @JanekWarchol - see updates.

Comment: It still doesn't work.  I've put the command into my `.gnomerc`, `.xinitrc` and `.xsession` and there is no result (the files are marked as executable, so there should be no problems with that).  What's probably most interesting is that i have another command in `.gnomerc` (`xbacklight -set 70`) and it works.

Comment: Does `xset` work for you if you write it in these files?

Comment: @JanekWarchol - I've never tried them 8-).

Comment: @JanekWarchol - see updates.

Comment: Still doesn't work and I don't know why (i suppose two possible reasons: my system is botched or the settings from gnome GUI overwrite it).  Anyway, you surely deserve to have your answer accepted and upvoted for all your effort!  I suppose your answers should work forr others.

Comment: @JanekWarchol - thank you, the above were the methods I was able to find by searching, I didn't see any other methods beyond these so I'm at a loss.

Comment: i'm hoping to reinstall my Ubuntu in a few days, and i'll check if it works on a fresh installation.